# Is swearing allowed in the comment section?

Tags: discussion

I was just wondering if it is unacceptable to use "swear words" here on the network.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: Unacceptable anywhere (comments, question, answers)

Comment: I by no means have a clean mouth, but I cannot think of any situation where swearing in a comment would be anything but immature, inappropriate, argumentative, or non-constructive. I would challenge you to give an example where an idea expressed in a comment could no longer be expressed without swearing. The only exception I can think of is if somehow the word itself were explicitly the topic (but on SO I cannot imagine that; on English, certainly).

Comment: **[What is the SE version of Seven Dirty Words?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773)** -- "Some words, when present in a comment, make it eligible for instant, automatic one-flag deletion..."

Comment: @JasonC: How about programming filters and such? The *specific* swear-word is not the topic, but it might be used in an example.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sure; it really depends on context. I would still count that as the word itself being the topic, rather than using the word to convey some meaning, although really it would be a safer bet to try and find a different word as an example if possible. Disclosure: I am, personally, not easily offended, and would not be likely to complain about swear words being used as the topic when e.g. discussing filters - but I recognize that they are poorly received even in these contexts, and I think it's important for all to remember that if you want your comment to be well-received.

Comment: If I wanted to provide an example for a filtering algorithm (I don't, since it's madness to do so, but **if** I was) I am pretty sure I could manage to come up with some example data that didn't contain expletives.

Answer (score 6):

For example commenting like *RTFM* is strongly discouraged.
Link the appropriate FM section with a short, nice comment instead <sup>1</sup>.

*"Swearing"* , or using *"Swear words"* in comments, tend's to be considered *rude or offensive* (and being flagged so in turn).

---

<sub>1) [Caught a nice recent sample.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094564/how-to-generate-an-assembly-file-from-c-source-code-for-dummies)</sub>

Comment: I don't think there's anything offensive about "Read the formidable manual".

Comment: @remyabel  Good point. But you well know, that's not the _real common interpretation_ of the acronym ;-D ...

Comment: That link doesn't work.

Comment: @self It doesn't work unless you're able to see deleted questions. The text I had used in my comment there was: `Did you read the manual actually?. Could you elaborate about what doesn't "work for your code" please? Does that code compile regularly?` Where I linked the manual in question in.

Answer (score 5):

From the five year old FAQ on MSE, [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites), [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/231078) states:

> ## No.
>
> Expletives are not acceptable behavior on meta or any other Stack
> Exchange site. If you can't effectively communicate what you need to
> say without resorting to lowest common denominator cursing, then keep
> it to yourself.
>
> If you use expletives, you will get a warning.
>
> If you continue to use expletives, you will be placed on [timed
> suspension](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

The [Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) page from the help center also says:

> **Don't be a jerk**. These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>
> - Inappropriate language or attention. Avoid vulgar terms ...

People occasionally use swear words, however whether or not something is considered *rude or offensive* of course depends on the comment in question.

Keep in mind that it's clear the intent is to prohibit swear words, as initial drafts of the [Be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240594/proposed-new-code-of-conduct-for-all-stack-exchange-sites) policy stated:

> Please note that expletives are not allowed. If you use expletives on
> this site, you may be issued a warning or a suspension.

and:

> - **Choose your words carefully.** [Expletives are generally not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites);
>   don't be vulgar. Think before posting an inflammatory remark, even as
>   a joke: if it isn't appropriate at work or home, it is not appropriate
>   here.

Answer (score 5):

As well as falling foul of the "be nice" rule, swearwords are one of the things that might get Stack Overflow added to a company's "not safe for work" site list.

People can think of enough reasons why they might want to block Stack Overflow, so let's not add to those with a perfectly legitimate one.