# What the ..f***?

Tags: discussion, support

How to handle questions under which the OP says WTF when they receive a downvote (a fair one)? Other things that were said:

> WHAT THE F*** STACKOVERFLOW?? ARE YOU F****** KIDDING ME?

We are helping for free here, I don't think we deserve this!

---

The user has since deleted that comment. However, I still do not think this is cool. I mean, are we going to hear bad words until one of us tries to answer?

Comment: [Swearing is not tolerated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277702/2564301) - but you probably did know that already. Comments get flagged, a dime gets put into a jar, and when it overfloweth, that person is going to get a personalized e-mail: "Hello [insert-username], we notcied that ..." Anything else necessary?

Comment: @RadLexus, well I feel that got *totally* away with this, since the people answering the question now do not have a clue about it. I mean I feel that I don't keep *this* question alive, he will get his question answered, but no "punishment".

Comment: Funny, though, to reinterpret the current answers: "Your original version was better. It just needed one tweak." I don't know how fast a user's Swear Jar contents erodes away - maybe it's one of those purposely Hidden Stats so we don't abuse it.

Comment: Thank you @RadLexus for taking this care of. Shall you answer the question or should I delete it?

Comment: Meh, Stack Overflow is a big place. Sometimes people will get helped who don't deserve it.

Comment: Good point @Pekka웃, but I wanted to speak that out! I mean it's just like the bad thing you see in the streets and you don't just move along, leaving it unnoticed, you report it to the people you should. :D

Comment: The only surprising thing about this is that anyone would find such behaviour from posters suprising.

Comment: Well yeah, but this is an edge case. This guy is not a help vampire user. As Martijn says, best to just flag and move on.

Comment: @Pekka웃, got it!

Comment: @gsamaras I have no idea why you feel so inclined to post a question on meta. You think this is simply a case of me being an immature brat? No. When your question acquires 3 downvotes within less than a minute, after spending an ample amount of time on the question, and spending the last hour working on a solution, you get upset. This isn't grade school where you have a meeting with the principal over insignificant issues. We are all adults here. Just move on. I'm tired of getting downvotes when I work so hard on questions, while other EXTREMELY simple and stupid questions get hundreds of rep!

Comment: @43.52.4D. he did the right thing posting here. This site is [designed to be unwelcoming to those who act as immature brats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773)

Comment: What's immature was a bunch of "mature adults" coming over to my question because of this Meta post and downvoting me simply to spite me. Anyone can see my question is about as good a question as one can ask for. I did not ask to be spoonfed. I asked my question clearly with example code I've tried. The "mature adults" who browse SO shouldn't downvote for personal reasons. This site is ALREADY quite unwelcoming in that I received 3 downvotes within 30 seconds of posting, despite not making a SINGLE "rude" comment. You guys should rethink which questions REALLY deserve a downvote...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Flag the comment and move on. Leave it to the moderators to deal with the behaviour.

And if enough members of the community agree comments are automatically deleted if enough flags are cast (which can be as few as [just one flag, depending on the content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266161/why-do-comment-flags-sometimes-take-immediate-effect)). Which is exactly what happened to that specific comment; it was deleted because it had been flagged. The OP did not delete it themselves.

In the end, just focus on the post and not who posted it or their attitude. If the question is on-topic and is helpful to future visitors then it doesn't matter how angry the OP was when it was posted.

Comment: worth noting that comments with f-word (and some other "trigger-words") are [deleted immediately with single flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266161/839601)

Comment: "Flag the comment and move on." Apropos of which, are there any plans in motion for something that could hinder the 'Meta effect'?

Comment: @gnat: I had left the number of flags deliberately vague; I've added a link to that post now.